# Вызов функции из другой формы С++\CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Еесть форма1 в которой я пытаюсь вызвать функцию из формы2

```
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    Form2 ^form2 = gcnew Form2 ();
    form2->initialize();
}
```

В форме2 реализован метод

```
void initialize()
{
  //code...
}
```

Внутри формы 2 метод initialize работает нормально, а при вызове из формы1 вылетает ошибка:

```
 error C3767: ProgramName::Form2::initialize: функции-кандидаты недоступны  c:\projects\ProgramName\ProgramName\Form1.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай initialize public т.е.

```
    public void initialize()
    {
      //code...
    }
```

Comment: Действительно получилось, спасибо. Только с двоеточием

    public: void initialize()    
    {
       //code...    
    }